# What does "most" mean in "the most general solution of $\tan\theta=-1$ and $\cos\theta=\frac{1}{\sqrt2}$"?

Tags: trigonometry

What does "most" mean here?

> The *most* general solution of $\tan\theta = -1$ and $\cos\theta = \dfrac{1}{\sqrt2}$ is:
>
> **(A)** $n\pi +  \dfrac{7\pi}{4}$, $n\in I$
>
> **(B)** $n\pi+{(-1)^n} \cdot \dfrac{7\pi}{4}$, $n\in I$
>
> **(C)** $2n\pi+\dfrac{7\pi}{4}$, $n\in I$
>
> **(D)** none of these

Comment: $I$ refers to integers?  Just curious about that. I've seen this symbol once for integers, but  $\mathbb{Z}$ is more common.

Comment: Yeah $I$ as in integers

Answer (score 3):

The **most general solutions** means this: each of the $4$ suggested answers defines a set $A$ of some numbers. Most general solution means:

1. the set $A$ suggested in the answer is indeed a solution set
2. that set $A$ is super-set of any other solution set $B$